# Database connection lost when reading from Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am new to Spring Kafka and I would say Kafka in general. But I am trying to consume a Kafka topic and then populate a database with the events received, so we have this:

Kafka Topics -> Application listener -> Database.

So I was wondering what's the approach when the connection to the database is lost for whatever reason; so this:

Kafka Topics -> Application listener (with one object read) X Database.

One of my though suggestions is to stop the lister and then somehow turn it back on when the database recovers. Also what's going to happen with the element that we already read from the topics?

The data set os really big so reading from the beginning is not really an option.

Also I do not own the Kafka producer. I am just a consumer using an external source.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which database? Are you familiar with Kafka Connect Framework?

Comment: I am not. I shall take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what's the approach when the connection to the database is lost

You should not be using auto commits in your consumer code.

The short answer is that if you are not committing to the database, you should not be committing the consumed offsets back to Kafka. This way, in the event of retries, you have up to the Kafka retention period for the topic to push the data into the database.

A common pattern for this type of "database replay" uses a compacted Kafka topic in which you are guaranteed to preserve the most recent value of every unique Kafka message key.

Comment: can we stop and start kafka listener? i need can we control it? just my doubt @cricket_007

Comment: exactly this is just ideas running through my head because I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: You should read about how consumer groups work in Kafka. If you restart a process with the same group id, it'll only start at that offset, not the beginning of the topic. If you let your code automatically commit offsets, then you risk messages not getting to the database for a variety of reasons, not only the database being down